# Running with SOLR and Lucene together in Sitecore

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Does anybody know how to have Lucene and Solr together in the same Sitecore Instalation?

Sitecore states that is possible here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene

> You can mix Lucene and Solr, and, for example, use Solr for xDB and
>   Lucene for content search at the same time. If an index is small, it
>   is much easier to manage as a Lucene index because there is little to
>   no overhead to set it up.

But there is no reference on how to configure it.

Any advise is welcome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In words, your analytic indexes will be using SOLR and your content search indexes will be using Lucene.

To configure your analytic indexes to use SOLR, you can check the following documentation from Sitecore: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_processing_server#_Solr_configuration

By default, Sitecore already configured Lucene to be used for Content Search. So, for this, there is no change required.

However, I am not sure that SOLR and Lucene can be used for Content Search or xDB at the same time because of its configuration. For example, the Content Search makes use of the index configuration master, web and core. If you decide to use SOLR for Content Search, you will need to disable  the Lucene configuration file from the Include folder.

Thanks

Comment: Updated Sitecore docs say that this *should* be possible (see bottom of this article) https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene